# How can I labeled the X axis and Y axis in yellowbrick plot? The code is I used is show below

Tags: python, plot, jupyter, visualizer, yellowbrick

How can I labeled the X axis and Y axis in yellowbrick plot? The code is I used is show below.

```
from yellowbrick.regressor import PredictionError

Visualizer = PredictionError(LL_dt)
Visualizer.fit(X_train,y_train)
Visualizer.score(X_test,y_test)
Visualizer.poof()
```

I tried adding

```
Visualizer.ax.set_xlabel("Measured")
Visualizer.ax.set_ylabel("Predicted")
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "Visualizer.poof()". add your xlabel and ylabel code right after score.

```
Visualizer = PredictionError(LL_dt)
Visualizer.fit(X_train,y_train)
Visualizer.score(X_test,y_test)
Visualizer.ax.set_xlabel("Measured")
Visualizer.ax.set_ylabel("Predicted")
```